# Highlight Line of Code

Tags: feature-request

I just answered a question in which the OP was missing a comma in a bunch of nested parameters.

It would be really handy to be able to highlight a line of code

I'm thinking a different background colour. Alternatively - but inferiorly - with an icon to the side.

Comment: I guess you mean this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30304222/ I tend to use some text like "----------------^here" or similar.

Comment: Gifts for all:  ↑, →, ↓, ←

Comment: I'm not sure about that. This could encourage the number of answers that contain 2 changed lines in a 30+ line code block and a "try this" without further explanation. At the same time, if you could actually see what was changed in that code block, these kind of answers wouldn't be utterly useless for people that just stumble upon the question.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32705/248731

Comment: Also useful for indicating the line known to throw an exception,  SEGV, std.

Answer (score 20):

I'm active mostly in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), and I tend to do something like:

```py
def broken(func, args):
    print func, args
            # ^ note comma required
    do_something_with(args)
    return func
```

You can apply this to any language supporting comment lines. You can do more complex/fancier things like:

```py
def broken(func, args):
    print func, args  # note comma required
    do_something_with(args)
    return func
```

which is achieved as follows:

```html
<pre><code>def broken(func, args):
    <b>print func, args  # note comma required</b>
    do_something_with(args)
    return func</code></pre>
```

but I think that's generally unnecessary.

Comment: If you go for the "fancier" option, you need to take care to escape characters that have special meaning in HTML. Eg:`<` as `&lt;` and `&` as `&amp;`.

Comment: I got error: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. "

Comment: Don't do "fancier things". As this post shows, it's brittle and will easily break. (I believe, with the change in code highlighting library, that you can either have bold code or highlighted code.)