# Adding a Highlighter Tool to Posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**I would like to see a highlighter tool added to StackOverflow**, for this reason:
Let's say that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022743/4475997) answers your question. Knowing that it has `31946` characters (Taken from [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42151/333586)), you have a lot of reading to do. Even though this answer has impeccable formatting that sorts everything into sections, there may be a few lines that *you want to really stand out* from the rest so you can *come and go back to them easily*.

A highlighter with scrollbar marks (See below) in this situation would completely solve the problem.

**It would work like this:** <sub><sup>(Other ideas welcome, please comment/answer!)</sup></sub>
**Equip the highlighter by:** Quickly double clicking on any empty space.
**To highlight text:** Drag, triple click, ect. to select some text.
**To un-highlight text:** Select highlighted text.

The end result of the highlighting would look the same as if you searched  for text in Google Chrome's [find bar](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95635?hl=en), including the clickable marks on the right scrollbar that you would use to "jump" to one of your highlighted sections.

An example when line "My solution to this is a highlighter tool." is highlighted:
[image: Highlighter Example]

Other <sup><sub>(incomplete)</sub></sup> ideas to discuss include:

- A simple color picker (Like [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/1b0e1893237bcac65485f9fbf417b36786b37986/687474703a2f2f696d6731312e686f7374696e67706963732e6e65742f706963732f3735353034333230313331303235313231363033436f6c6f727069636b6572666f726a51756572792e706e67))
- A way to remove all the highlighting in a post (Button/Right click drop-down menu option?)

Please answer with your opinion on *if* this should be implemented, and if you agree with the specifications on *how* I thought it should be implemented.

<sup><sub>This is not a duplicate of "[Highlight Line of Code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294592/highlight-line-of-code)" as this question applies to all of a post, and not just code.</sub></sup>

Comment: I don't see how turning an answer to a rainbow will be useful for regular concrete Q&A posts - if you need multiple sections/highlighting better course of actions likely is to split or close the question. (Purposely broad canonical duplicate targets can't serve as justification of a feature for everyone from my point of view).

Comment: I think it's up for people who answer to emphasize and simplify their answers. Markdown is pretty enough for everything

Comment: So... these highlights are only supposed to show to the user who highlighted them and would have no effect for other users visiting? Because there are some browser add-ons out there already which will do exactly that for you. There's really no need for us to implement it into the site.

Comment: TL;DR: if you want something in your otherwise-too-long post to stand out, use a TL;DR

Comment: The real solution here is to write more concise posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highlights are only visible to the people who did the highlighting, and it is already possible through [a Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-simple-highlighter/hhlhjgianpocpoppaiihmlpgcoehlhio).

I haven't tried it yet, but it sounds like it does what you are looking for, minus the scrollbar marks.