# Piece-of-code-highlight/error highlight for Stack Overflow (and possibly others)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code

**Similar questions**

I have checked some previous questions/answers like this one: *[Highlight Line of Code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294592/highlight-line-of-code)*

But I did not like the answer and this can be troublesome.

**Proposal**

Let's say I post a big (but reproducible piece of code), and let's say multiple lines are with errors. I would personally prefer to see an underline red (like an IDE) that you can hover and the user can post the error, so for example, line 24 has a highlight on offset 15 to 24 with a red underline to hover and see: `NullReferenceException`.

This would reduce the time needed to answer (as you need to differentiate between what's a comment and what is a comment for the reader, so the user needs to strip a lot - which is recommended, but not for the answerer).

**What would this proposal resolve?**

1. Read-to-answer time.
2. Better-quality questions.
3. Improvement on the code block side, which is technically the main point of Stack Overflow.
4. Better report review - as we would see quicker what the user is talking about and what he's/she's trying to explain. The communication bit is fundamental for a site like Stack Overflow, so giving more options to someone to explain what they are trying to say, in my opinion, is better.
5. A highlight to a piece of code would solve as well what they are trying to say as well as the error one. It makes it easier to reproduce or even resolve before even trying the solution yourself.

A very good quality question resolves all of these. But we can make good quality questions with good quality code reading.

This is my first post on Meta on something I've been noticing for quite some time. I hope the community at least consider the possibility, as the current implementation is just a syntax highlight with not-so-many features...

Comment: I'm not sure how this would be implemented (perhaps people could suggest syntax?), but I'd love to see a feature like this (though probably just allowing a line to be emphasized, no need for fancy on-hover stuff).  It would make many posts much clearer.

Comment: Why can't you just use an embedded comment within the code to indicate the line(s) of interest?

Comment: Walls of code are terrible, I know. My proposal is merely to help the answerer quickely identify the problem since the answer on the other meta question was to add comments. Between comments and a simple formatting, I'd rather go with formatting.

Comment: @CodyGray please see my answer on Laurel's post, I explain a bit further

Comment: Is it the poster who has to add the formatting or is it automated? If it's the user, I'm not sure how that helps as they can already put a comment pointing exactly where the problem is.

Comment: While I think this is a terrible idea because it would massively increase complexity (read - bugs), one simple improvement to the code block would be to add line numbers. This would make it much easier to reference a section of the code when replying to the OP.

Comment: I agree with @mark_b

Comment: @mark_b Line numbers would be great, as long as we can copy the code block without also grabbing the line numbers. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring something like gist.github.

Answer (score 10):

Where does the red underline come from?

Is it special formatting? If that's the case, it just seems like it would mess up code more often than not. Many new users fail to use the appropriate formatting for a simple code block now.

Is it done automatically? I've seen sites that can run code in your browser, and some will underline errors. Few of those support more than a small handful of languages, and those that do need to be constantly updated to keep with that new version that just came out. And none of those support anything complicated. Not even my own IDE with plugins seems to be able to support the framework I use 100%.

---

My preference: Manually add a comment to your code to indicate where the error is. Or, better, make your code so short that you don't even need to do that.

Comment: I hate walls of code just like the guy next door. Except, not everyone follows this. You and I know how to write it properly. It would be merely to explain what is wrong instead of commenting. Automatically doing that would be pretty good, but if the error is at runtime it's hard to identify. My idea is, when posting some complex code (which does not mean it's a code block, just complex), to highlight parts of code and make comments where appropriate. This would help

Comment: @LuccaFerri But what is the advantage over a comment like we can do now?

Comment: you would be proactive to write what is wrong (or line numbers as described above) instead of explaining in a comment. The whole point of the post is to simplify how a question with code is made, not necessarily the error highlight I think. The community gave good ideas, but I've been downvoted to hell so I can't think how editing would be helpful. Check the thread on the main post

Comment: @LuccaFerri "*you would be proactive to write what is wrong (or line numbers as described above) instead of explaining in a comment*" Many people already do that - they describe the problem, then in the code, they leave a comment to the effect of `//problem is here` or similar. Some even cite the error they got which includes a line number and simply add a `//this is line 42` in the code which relates to the error message. Both of these seem simple enough to use when writing a question. Your suggestion seems to have similar complexity - markup instead of a comment to identify some code.

Answer (score 8):

##### Let's just continue to use code comments to indicate the line with the error or other area which is desired to be highlighted

The ability to put comments in code is nearly ubiquitous across (almost) all programming languages. Indicating things like where the error, *why* something is done a certain way, or what's been changed (in an example in an SO answer, but usually not in production code) are some of the things such comments are for. If we can't get users to use an already existing, default feature of the language they are using, I'm skeptical that we'd get them to use other additional formatting that's unique to Stack Overflow, unless there's a GUI which basically makes it required.

While formatting of code within the code format block might be helpful in very limited circumstances, I doubt that it would be used all that much. We already struggle to have users post questions with properly formatted basic code blocks. In addition, such additional formatting within code blocks could be substantially abused. Code is *much* more readable as just straight text.

To have any significant amount of reasonable use, there would need to be a GUI built to have people enter their code along with the errors and to indicate what line the error occurs on. While such a GUI would probably be beneficial, it's not a small amount of work to have it applicable over a large spectrum of questions/languages.

Another part of this is that Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow uses [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/). Other than using HTML for the code blocks (see below) there isn't anything in CommonMark which would allow this. The method chosen would need to be compatible for editing both with the above mentioned GUI and just with straight text. It would need to be something which isn't easy to mess up with simple text editing (e.g. it couldn't just be a specified line number within the code block, as those might change with editing by the OP or others).

Overall, this is something which is **much** easier to include in the code block as just a code comment and already has near-universal support.

##### Formatting within code blocks is already available, but is almost never used (which is a good thing, IMO)

You can already apply different formatting within code blocks, including having a different color, by using HTML to generate the code block and then adding additional formatting. You can use `<a>` elements to get a different color text (link color), along with a tooltip, using the `title` attribute. For details about what HTML can be used on Stack Overflow, see: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/271271)

Note: The highlight.js syntax highlighter will remove any formatting in a `<code>` block and apply its own formatting. If you're going to use an HTML `<pre><code>foobar</code></pre>` block to add your own formatting, as shown in the example below, then you need to be sure to [turn off syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/271271) for that code block or for the entire post.

###### Example

###### Formatted `<pre><code>` block

```
function hello() {
  const foo = "bold, italics, superscript, subscript, keyboard, strike-through";
  console.log('hello')); // This line has a tooltip
  
}
```

###### The Markdown/HTML which produced the above formatted `<pre><code>` block

```html
<!-- language: none -->
<pre><code>function hello() {
  const foo = "<strong>bold</strong>, <i>italics</i>, <sup>superscript</sup>, <sub>subscript</sub>, <kbd>keyboard</kbd>, <s>strike-through</s>";
  <a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412823" title="This is the line with an error. It has an intentional syntax error.">console.log('hello')); // This line has a tooltip</a>
  <img src="/oisajfosidjfoi" alt="// Another line with a tooltip" title="hello there. This uses an &lt;img&gt;.">
}</code></pre>
```

Personally, I would strongly discourage any significant amount of such formatting, but it might be useful in some very limited circumstances. However, it's not something which I'd expect a new user to do, and certainly not do reasonably.

Comment: Using the wrong comment character sequences make the syntax highlighting a mess (e.g., it is [complicated in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766441/how-to-use-comments-in-react/30766542#30766542) and may even be React version dependent). It would be nice with a single meta post with all the comment character sequences rules for [the supported languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109) (incl. some examples of what is not allowed officially (e.g., "`//`" in CSS)). Differences, if any, between the highlighter and the official character sequences could also be listed.